# No type named 'unique_ptr' in namespace 'std' when compiling under LLVM/Clang

Tags: c++11, c-preprocessor, unique-ptr, llvm-clang, c++03

I'm catching a compile error when attempting to use `unique_ptr` on Apple platforms with `-std=c++11`:

```
$ make
c++ -std=c++11 -DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -fPIC -march=native -Wall -Wextra -pipe -c 3way.cpp
In file included ...
./smartptr.h:23:27: error: no type named 'unique_ptr' in namespace 'std'
    using auto_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T>;
                     ~~~~~^
./smartptr.h:23:37: error: expected ';' after alias declaration
    using auto_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T>;
```

According to Marshall Clow, who I consider an expert on the [C++ Standard Library with Clang and Apple](http://marshall.calepin.co/c-and-xcode-46.html):

> Technical Report #1 (TR1) was a set of library additions to the C++03
>   standard. Representing the fact that they were not part of the
>   "official" standard, they were placed in the namespace std::tr1.
>
> In c++11, they are officially part of the standard, and live in the
>   namespace std, just like vector and string. The include files no
>   longer live in the "tr1" folder, either.

Take aways:

- Apple and C++03 = use TR1 namespace
- Apple and C++11 = use STD namespace
- Use `LIBCPP_VERSION` to detect `libc++`

Now, here's what I have in `smartptr.h`:

```
#include <memory>

// Manage auto_ptr warnings and deprecation in C++11
// Microsoft added template aliases to VS2015
#if (__cplusplus >= 201103L) || (_MSC_VER >= 1900)
  template<typename T>
    using auto_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T>;
#else
  using std::auto_ptr;
#endif // C++11
```

I think the last thing to check is the `__APPLE__` define, and here it is:

```
$ c++ -x c++ -dM -E - < /dev/null | grep -i apple
#define __APPLE_CC__ 6000
#define __APPLE__ 1
#define __VERSION__ "4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)"
#define __apple_build_version__ 5030040
```

Why am I receiving a ***`error: no type named 'unique_ptr' in namespace 'std'`*** when using `-std=c++11`?

---

I think these are the four test cases. It attempts to exercise the four configurations from the cross product of: {C++03,C++11} x {libc++,libstdc++}.

- c++ -c test-clapple.cxx

  - OK
- c++ -stdlib=libc++ -c test-clapple.cxx

  - OK
- c++ -std=c++11 -c test-clapple.cxx

  - FAIL
- c++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -c test-clapple.cxx

  - OK

Here is the test driver. Be sure to test it on OS X so you get the full effects of the TR1 namespace in 2015.

```
$ cat test-clapple.cxx

// c++ -c test-clapple.cxx
// c++ -stdlib=libc++ -c test-clapple.cxx
// c++ -std=c++11 -c test-clapple.cxx
// c++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -c test-clapple.cxx

#include <memory>

// Manage auto_ptr warnings and deprecation in C++11
#if (__cplusplus >= 201103L) || (_MSC_VER >= 1900)
  template<typename T>
    using auto_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T>;
#else
    using std::auto_ptr;
#endif // C++11

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return argc;
}
```

Comment: There is no `std::tr1::auto_ptr` on any platform ever that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Jonathan, My bad... I realized that was a mistake, and it was changed. But I only changed it in the test case I posted. Let me update it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> And the CFE Devs specifically told me to use that code;

No they didn't. They told you to do something similar if you want to use `shared_ptr`, because for C++03  `<tr1/memory>` defines `std::tr1::shared_ptr` and for C++11 `<memory>` defines `std::shared_ptr`.

But you're not using `shared_ptr`. If you want to use `auto_ptr` then it's just `std::auto_ptr`, everywhere, which is always defined in `<memory>`.

I think you've misunderstood Marshall's comment and you're overcomplicating things. What you quoted (*'In c++11, they are officially part of the standard, and live in the namespace std, just like vector and string. The include files no longer live in the "tr1" folder, either.'*) is not Apple-specific or Clang-specific, it applies to all compilers. But since `auto_ptr` was never part of TR1 and never in `<tr1/memory>` it's irrelevant that the contents of TR1 are now in namespace `std`, because what you're trying to use was never included in TR1.

You should not be using TR1 **at all** here.

```
# include <memory>

// Manage auto_ptr warnings and deprecation in C++11
#if (__cplusplus >= 201103L)
template<typename T>
using auto_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T>;
#else
using std::auto_ptr;
#endif // C++11
```

This should be correct for modern compilers, but won't work on the stupid configuration that comes with XCode, which is a modern version of Clang that supports C++11 and the libstdc++ from GCC 4.2 which is nearly ten years old and doesn't support `unique_ptr`.

To cope with the default OS X toolchain this works:

```
#include <memory>

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
# ifdef __clang__
#  if __has_include(<forward_list>)
// either using libc++ or a libstdc++ that's new enough to have unique_ptr
#   define HAVE_UNIQUE_PTR 1
#  endif
# else // not clang, assume unique_ptr available
#  define HAVE_UNIQUE_PTR 1
# endif
#endif

#ifdef HAVE_UNIQUE_PTR
template<typename T> using auto_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T>;
#else
using std::auto_ptr;
#endif
```

This works by using the presence of `<forward_list>` as an indicator of whether the standard library clang is using supports `std::unique_ptr`.

If clang is using libc++ as its standard library then all versions support `unique_ptr` and also provide `<forward_list>`, so the test passes.

If clang is using libstdc++ then whether `unique_ptr` is supported depends on the libstdc++ version. `unique_ptr` was added to libstdc++ in GCC 4.3, which is the same version that added `<forward_list>`, so if that header is available then `unique_ptr` will be too. If you are using clang with the ancient libstdc++ that ships with the Apple toolchains (from GCC 4.2) then `unique_ptr` is not supported, but neither is `<forward_list>`, so the test fails and you use `auto_ptr` instead.

That should work for any GCC/libstdc++, Clang/libc++ or Clang/libstdc++ combination found in the wild. I don't know what is needed for VC++/Dinkumware and Clang/Dinkumware, from your answer it looks like maybe you would just change the first condition to:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L || _MSC_VER >= 1600
```

Comment: You're right, thanks. The header locations do depend on TR1. Maybe that's why I went down the rabbit hole...

Comment: I'm still getting ***`error: no type named 'unique_ptr' in namespace 'std'`*** when compiling with `-std=c++11` and *without* `-stdlib=libc++` under Apple's Clang (3.4 SVN) and LLVM's Clang (3.6).

Comment: That will be because it uses the ancient libstdc++ shipped on Mac OS X, which comes from GCC 4.2, so even though Clang supports C++ and defines `__cplusplus == 201103L` when you use `-std=c++11` the std::lib doesn't have any C++11 support. So you might need to check the std::lib being used, but you still don't want anything involving TR1.

Comment: So, it appears when using `-stdlib=libc++`, LLVM puts `unique_ptr` in `std::`, and ***not*** `std::tr1`.

Comment: Because `unique_ptr` was never part of TR1. No compiler has ever put it in `std::tr1`. As I said above, if you are trying to use switch between `auto_ptr` and `unique_ptr` then TR1 is completely irrelevant and you should not be doing anything with `std::tr1` or any `<tr1/xxx>` header.

Comment: Do you have a Mac available for testing? I can give you a test program that duplicates the problem. `c++ -std=c++11 -c <file>` fails to compile because it claims `error: no type named 'unique_ptr' in namespace 'std'`. It does exactly what you tell me to do.

Comment: Because  the ancient libstdc++ on Mac OS X has no C++11 support. As stated four comments above this one. `unique_ptr` was new in C++11. It was not in C++03, and it was not in TR1. If you use a version of libstdc++ from 2007 then you're not going to get C++11 features even if you use `-std=c++11` on the command-line, because of the linear nature of time. Note the last sentence I added to the answer above an hour ago.