# How to detect -stdlib=libc++ in the preprocessor?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, c-preprocessor, libc++

I think this is part of the problem at [No type named 'unique_ptr' in namespace 'std' when compiling under LLVM/Clang](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31655462). [According to Marshall Clow](http://marshall.calepin.co/c-and-xcode-46.html), I can detect `-stdlib=libc++` via `_LIBCPP_VERSION`:

> If you're writing cross-platform code, sometimes you need to know what
>   standard library you are using. In theory, they should all offer
>   equivalent functionality, but that's just theory. Sometimes you just
>   need to know. The best way to check for libc++ is to look for the
>   preprocessor symbol _LIBCPP_VERSION. If that's defined, then you're
>   using libc++.
>
> ```
> #ifdef  _LIBCPP_VERSION
> //  libc++ specific code here
> #else
> //  generic code here
> #endif
> ```

Unfortunately, that breaks down with Apple's Clang (3.4-SVN) and the Clang (3.6) I built from sources after downloading from the LLVM project. I'm guessing the test is only valid under Xcode.

How can I reliably detect `-stdlib=libc++` in the preprocessor?

---

Here is the test case:

```c++
$ cat test-clapple.cxx

// Need to test {C++03,C++11} x {libc++, no libc++}

// c++ -c test-clapple.cxx
//     - OK
// c++ -stdlib=libc++ -c test-clapple.cxx
//     - OK
// c++ -std=c++11 -c test-clapple.cxx
//     - FAILS, no type named 'unique_ptr' in namespace 'std'
// c++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -c test-clapple.cxx
//     - OK

#include <ciso646>

#if (__cplusplus >= 201103L) || (_MSC_VER >= 1600)
# pragma message "C++11"
#elif (__cplusplus >= 199711L)
# pragma message "C++03"
#endif

#if (_LIBCPP_VERSION)
# pragma message "libc++"
#else
# pragma message "no libc++"
#endif

#if defined(__apple_build_version__)
# pragma message "Apple build"
#else
# pragma message "non-Apple build"
#endif

#if (__cplusplus >= 201103L) || (_MSC_VER >= 1600) // C++11
# include <memory>
#else
# include <tr1/memory>
#endif

// Manage auto_ptr warnings and deprecation in C++11
#if (__cplusplus >= 201103L) || (_MSC_VER >= 1600)
  template<typename T>
    using auto_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T>;
#else
  using std::auto_ptr;
#endif // C++11

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return argc;
}
```

---

This project does not use Autotools, Cmake, Boost, or other external libraries or frameworks.

Comment: Xcode is not magic; are you sure this isn't already ready to go? It's possible that Xcode sets `_LIBCPP` on the commandline for you but it seems more likely to have been set by libc++ itself, no?

Comment: `_LIBCPP_VERSION` is the correct check, but you have to actually include a standard library header before it will be defined.

Comment: So perhaps you're checking the macro before including library headers? If library headers define the macro, that won't work. Can you show a specific minimal program and compiler invocation that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Your test case is wrong, because you're not including a standard library header before trying to test which standard library implementation is in use. See my answer below. In any case this is probably not important because the question you say it's part of is based on another mistaken premise.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The only effect `-stdlib=libc++` has on the preprocessor is to change the include paths it uses to find standard library headers, so you can't detect the presence of `-stdlib=libc++` on the command-line per se, you can only detect which standard library headers get included. Obviously you can't detect that without actually including one or more standard library headers.

If you include any libc++ header then `_LIBCPP_VERSION` will be defined, so the way to detect `-stdlib=libc++` is to include at least one C++ library header and check for `_LIBCPP_VERSION`.

In C++20 and later, it is recommend to `#include <version>`, which was created specifically for this purpose. Prior to C++20, it is recommended to `#include <ciso646>` which serves no purpose in C++ and declares nothing, but for libc++ does define the `_LIBCPP_VERSION` macro. However, for libstdc++ historically `<ciso646>` did *not* define any macros such as  `__GLIBCXX__` that can be used to detect libstdc++. That changed with GCC 6.1 so `<ciso646>` can be used now, but for older releases you need to include a different header to detect libstdc++.

Comment: You should be able to include `<ciso646>` (which also has no effect) on pretty much any C++ implementation, even libstdc++, and it should work just as well for detecting `_LIBCPP_VERSION`, right? Or does that have its own list of implementations that didn't/don't support it?

Comment: @hvd, oops, I was confusing `<cuchar>` and `<ciso646>`. Including the latter for libstdc++ doesn't do anything, not even define our versioning macros, see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65473

Comment: Ah, thanks for the report link. If it does work for libc++ though, then it might be enough for the OP.

Comment: ciso646 *does* define "or", "and" and others.

Comment: @dascandy, no, it shouldn't. In C++ those are keywords not macros, so they are pre-defined by the compiler. A footnote in the standard even says "177) In particular, including the standard header `<iso646.h>` or `<ciso646>` has no effect."

Comment: For future visitors, on MS Visual Studio 2015 with [`_MSC_EXTENSIONS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) set (the default) `<ciso646>` does create preprocessor definitions of those keywords. I haven't checked if this is still true in MS VS 2017.

Comment: Note that C++20 will have [`<version>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/version).

Comment: And note that C++20 will also [remove `<ciso646>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/ciso646), so to support that, some `__has_include` dance might need to happen (provided that libc++ will actually remove the header, of course).

Comment: There's no way that libc++ will actually remove the header, because people will still compile with C++14 (say), and include it.