# What is the portable way to forward-declare classes in an inline namespace in libc++?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, libc++

The following code doesn't compile only when I specify `-stdlib=libc++` to `clang++`:

```
namespace std {
  class mutex;
}

void f(std::mutex &x);

#include <mutex>

void f(std::mutex &x) { }
```

- http://goo.gl/Uqpv6f (gcc.godbolt.org)

> note: candidate found by name lookup is 'std::__1::mutex'

I understand what is `::__1` there,

- [Where does the __1 symbol come from when using LLVM's libc++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293394/where-does-the-1-symbol-come-from-when-using-llvms-libc)

but to my eyes, `libc++` breaks the API defined by the C++ standard:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex (well, this is not really a standard...)

It *should* be possible to forward-declare `std::mutex` because it should reside directly under `std`, shouldn't it?

Note that the compilation phase, rather than linking phase, is failing.  So I don't think the answer to my question should be along the line of "because libc++ employs a different ABI from GNU libstdc++..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but to my eyes, libc++ breaks the API defined by the C++ standard:

Actually, it does not. The standard specifies in [contents]:

> It is **unspecified** whether names declared in a specific
>   namespace are declared directly in that namespace or in an inline namespace inside that namespace.

libc++ is allowed to put `mutex` in `inline namespace __1`. Note that there are [good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11016220/2069064) for wanting inline namespaces, and typically as the user you don't even care if they exist or not.

To your specific question, you *can* still forward-declare `std::mutex` with libc++... you just have to include all the namespaces (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31657499/2069064) for how to detect -std=libc++):

```
namespace std {
#ifdef _LIBCPP_VERSION
    inline namespace __1 {
        struct mutex;
    }
#else
    struct mutex;
#endif
}
```

However, from [namespace.std]:

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a
>   namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified.

A forward-declaration is still a declaration, so even the above version which accounts for inline namespaces is undefined behavior. So prefer to do it the direct way:

```
#include <mutex>
```

Comment: Thanks for quoting the standard permitting libc++ to break my code. Well, I was sort of expecting it was written somewhere in the standard...  I think I need something like `#define _STD_BEGIN ...`

Comment: Adding a declaration, even a forward declaration, to `std` is UB.

Comment: @nodakai Technically, libc++ didn't break your code. Your code was broken. It just happened to work.

Comment: @T.C.  Thanks, good to know.  You could post it as an answer and I'd accept it