# How to check if libc++ is installed?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, libc++

I am building something from source. My system's gcc and stdlibc++ are too old, but there is a clang build I can use. By default, clang uses stdlibc++, but libc++ may optionally be installed for clang to use.

What is the best way to check if libc++ is installed with clang?

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: what system?  on various linuses use the package manager query switch for whatever package manager you have (apt, yum, rpm ...).  use man page or --help.

Comment: To use C++ you must use `clang++` explicitly as command.

Comment: similar Centos clang issue is documented in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840088/how-to-build-libcxx-and-libcxxabi-by-clang-on-centos-7

Comment: Your error is elsewhere. If you were explicitly linking libc++ and it is not installed, the linker would tell you it cannot find libc++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Slightly better answer than @n.n:

`printf "#include <ciso646>\nint main () {}" | clang -E -stdlib=libc++ -x c++ -dM - | grep _LIBCPP_VERSION`

If that prints something like: `#define _LIBCPP_VERSION 3700`, then you've got libc++.

Comment: This one liner is preferable; at least on my system, n.m.'s approach could not be altered without retyping the entire command. Could you explain what some of the symbols are, like <ciso646> and -E -dM? Also I would add that on a non-trivial system with many clang build versions, you can replace "clang" with path/to/particular-clang-build/bin/clang.

Comment: Regarding the `#include<ciso646>`, I refer you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657499/how-to-detect-stdlib-libc-in-the-preprocessor  (which amusingly enough is in response to another answer I gave), and `clang++ -E -dM` tells clang not to compile the source, but just to preprocess it (the `-E`) and then to print out all the things that are defined (the `-dM`)

Answer (score 6):

The most straightforward way to check if libc++ is installed is to use it on a trivial program:

```
 clang++ -xc++ -stdlib=libc++ - <<EOF
 int main(){}
 EOF
```

If this fails, you don't have libc++.

In a real-world application, add user-supplied compiler and linker options:

```
 clang++ $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -xc++ -stdlib=libc++ - <<EOF
```

so that the user has a chance to specify that libc++ is installed in a non-standard place.

Comment: [libc++ docs](http://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html) provide the details of what $(CXXFLAGS) and $(LDFLAGS) would be in a practical application.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to check if a library is installed:

Type `ldconfig -p | grep libc++` into the terminal. It does not matter what system you are using. If libc++ is not installed, the terminal will not say anything. If it is installed, it will display the available versions.

Comment: @okovko Check this out. It'll show you how to install software on your system. Try it. https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/7863/how-do-i-search-for-and-install-software-packages-in-fedora/ After that, we can delete this discussion since it is obsolete.

Comment: It would be nice to just install something fresh, but that is out of the question, as it is not my system.

Comment: @okovko Well, keep it handy just in case you can use it. Let's delete this discussion now that it's obsolete.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible you get a confusion that both gcc and clang do. To compile code as C++, you have to use `g++` instead of `gcc`, respectively `clang++` instead of `clang`.

I doubt the `libc++` libraries themselves are missing, since it's almost certain some program depends on them.

Comment: Well, it's about setting the compiler itself. cmake may call clang instead of clang++ internally, but I think it should have some variable to set the compiler (make itself has one)

Comment: I'd be surprised if the library were missing. Gcc should be able to link to that library if instructed.

Comment: ...deleting comments and downvoting is downright impolite! Lol