# Is it possible to use the standard C++17 <filesystem> facilities with Zig in C++ compiler mode?

Tags: c++, c++17, zig

I am just getting started with the Zig. I am using Zig 0.9.0 on Windows 10. One of the features that attracts me is using Zig as a C or C++ compiler or cross-compiler. I have used Zig successfully for some toy programs, but my luck ran out when I tried to use C++17's standard library filesystem facilities. Here is a minimal example;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <filesystem>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    std::string s("src/zigtest.cpp");
    std::filesystem::path p(s); 
    bool exists = std::filesystem::exists(p);
    printf( "File %s %s\n", s.c_str(), exists ? "exists" : "doesn't exist" );
    return 0;
}
```

If I attempt to build this with the following command;

```
zig c++ -std=c++17 src\zigtest.cpp
```

I get the following link error;

```
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: std::__1::__fs::filesystem::__status(std::__1::__fs::filesystem::path const&, std::__1::error_code*)
>>> referenced by ...
```

Incidentally, for a long time I didn't get this far, it turned out I needed to apply the -std=c++17 flag, until then I had this compile error rather than a link error;

```
src\zigtest.cpp:7:10: error: no member named 'filesystem' in namespace 'std'
```

Finally I'll note that (after some googling) I tried passing a -lstdc++fs flag, with no luck either. In that case I get;

```
error(link): DLL import library for -lstdc++fs not found
error: DllImportLibraryNotFound
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be solved in this PR. Jakub and Spex worked on it immediately after I linked them this question :^)

https://github.com/ziglang/zig/pull/10563

Comment: Thank you. Ironically, since what I was trying to do was build an executable for my friend who is on macOS (Intel) on my Windows box, I could have continued (I guess) without worrying about this (once I figured out how to retarget etc. - not obvious) I must admit I am so confused right now, for example the pull request talks about GNU and <filesystem> stuff not working on MSVC (itself a little puzzling MS tools have no problems with <filesystem>). I assumed that Zig is using Clang through and through yet here are references to GCC (GNU?) and MSVC. I'll figure it out over time.

Comment: I had already decided it might be easier to use an old Linux box, running Ubuntu 18.04, but I actually hit upon a much worse bug there that convinces me that Zig is not ready for prime-time for this kind of thing. The idea of a simple cross development C/C++ compiler is brilliant and the implementation is promising - but it's nowhere near there yet. Possibly no surprise to anyone but me. I spent a lot of time figuring out why my simple C++ program would crash on the Linux box, and eventually narrowed it down to an awe-inspiringly simple and reproduceable problem as follows (another comment)

Comment: The very simple C++ program below just crashes (illegal operation) on the line m[5] = 6 when built with zig c++ on Ubuntu 18.04LTS (zig 0.9.0). Works okay if you move the map variable into main() as a stack variable. Also works as expected on WIndows. Please let me know if it would be helpful to report the problem elsewhere, thanks.
`#include <stdio.h>`
`#include <map>`
`static std::map<int,int> m;`
`int main()`
`{`
    `m[5] = 6;`
    `printf( "m[5] = %d\n", m[5] );`
    `return 0;`
`}`

Answer (score 3):

A few comments:  The fact that you are seeing `std::__1::__fs::filesystem` means that you're using libc++.

Trying to link to `libstdc++fs` which is a gcc thing, wouldn't work even if you had it on your system.

What version of libc++ are you using?
The docs for libc++ are here:

- https://releases.llvm.org/8.0.0/projects/libcxx/docs/UsingLibcxx.html
- https://releases.llvm.org/9.0.0/projects/libcxx/docs/UsingLibcxx.html
- https://releases.llvm.org/10.0.0/projects/libcxx/docs/UsingLibcxx.html
  (and so on...)

They talk about using `<filesystem>` and what (if anything) you have to link to.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The Zig C++ build system is a little opaque (or maybe it is just my unfamiliarity) and it seems hard to find out what the underlying components and versions are. I am a little handicapped by being more familiar with MSVC than GCC or Clang too, sorry. Anyway, if I go Zig C++ --version I find it is Clang 13.0.1 (quite recent right?). I have no idea what version of libc++ I am using and I don't know how to find out. If I look at your llvm.org releases above, it seems I should either have to do nothing special (9,10) - or add -lc++fs (8).... (will add another comment)

Comment: I had already tried -lc++fs as a result of previous desperate googling - with the same disappointing result as -lstdc++fs (i,e, error - DLL import library for -lc++fs not found)

Comment: It's nice when I can refer to one of my own answers :-).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441490/how-to-check-if-libc-is-installed

Comment: Thanks I will check this when I get home tonight. I have a bad feeling about this one, my theory is that the Zig C++ compile chain is not setup for C++17, in the sense that this simple invocation of the standard library is going to defeat it. I have always been told that it is the Microsoft compiler that lags behind the standards committee, but on Visual Studio using <filesystem> has been easy for years.

Comment: #define _LIBCPP_VERSION 13000. So https://releases.llvm.org/13.0.0/projects/libcxx/docs/UsingLibcxx.html which says nothing at all about <filesystem>. But https://releases.llvm.org/12.0.0/projects/libcxx/docs/UsingLibcxx.html says "Starting with LLVM 9.0, support for <filesystem> is provided in the main library and nothing special is required to use <filesystem>." It looks like support for <filesystem> is now so bedded in they don't even mention it any more. Hmmmm, curiouser and curiouser.