# When compiling with MINGW gcc, overloaded new operator is not called for std::string

Tags: c++, gcc, stdstring, gcc9

This program (compiled with option `-std=c++17`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
void* operator new(std::size_t nrOfBytes) {
    printf("allocate %zd bytes on heap\n", nrOfBytes);
    void* p = malloc(nrOfBytes);
    if (p) {
        return p;
    } else {
       throw std::bad_alloc{};
    }
}
int main() {
    // new operator is called when compiled with Clang or MSVS or GCC 
    int* i = new int;
    delete i;
    // new operator is not called when compiled with GCC
    // but is called with Clang and MSVS 
    std::string str(2000, 'x');
    return 0;
}
```

when compiled with Clang or MSVS, prints:

> allocate 4 bytes on heap
>
> allocate 2016 bytes on heap

However, when compiled with GCC (Version 9.2.0 provided by MSYS on Windows) it only prints:

> allocate 4 bytes on heap

I am aware of short string optimization in GCC/libc++, but aren't 2000 chars too many for a short string? Is it a matter of SSO at all?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205929/discussion-on-question-by-angle-bracket-when-compiling-with-gcc-overloaded-new).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that GCC does not (or can't?) implement replacement of the global `operator new` and `operator delete` correctly when dynamic libraries are involved on Windows.

See bug reports e.g. [77726](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=77726), [82122](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82122) and [81413](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81413).

In your case `std::string`'s constructor and/or `std::allocator<char>::allocate` seem to be located in the standard library's dynamic library, so that the `operator new` it uses isn't being replaced correctly.

Comment: To further clarify: this behavior has only been observed when using GCC with libc++ on Windows provided by MSYS / MINGW. Every version of GCC/libstdc++ on Ubuntu I was able to test worked exactly like those programs compiled with Clang or MSVS. Moreover, it is clearly not a case of SSO when compiled with GCC, as `sizeof(str)` yields `32`.

Comment: @Angle.Bracket Do you mean libstdc++ instead of libc++?

Comment: I guess its called libc++ in MINGW

Comment: @Angle.Bracket libc++ usually refers to the standard library implementation of the LLVM project for clang. I don't think gcc is able to use it, mingw or not. But I may be wrong here.

Comment: @Angle.Bracket I guess you can verify whether you are using libstdc++ or libc++ using the answers [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657499/how-to-detect-stdlib-libc-in-the-preprocessor).

Comment: Just verified it: it's libstdc++